# C++/Pointer to a Structure/ validate members

Tags: c++, validation, int, structure

below is my structure which i expose to user to populate it by giving it some size using malloc.
the use passes me the pointer to this structure

```
typedef struct ServerConfiguration {
    wchar_t *IPAddress;
    USHORT PortNo;
    wchar_t *Title;
    int repeatCount;
    int timeout;
} ServerConfig;

ServerConfig *serverconfig = (ServerConfig*)malloc(sizeof(ServerConfig));
dcmServerconfig->IPAddress = L"localhost";
dcmServerconfig->Title = L"DVTK_MW_SCP";
dcmServerconfig->PortNo = 8080;
```

user doe not assign repeat count//
which points to some junk address loc //example repeatCount=380090700

i have another structure which has struct,

```
typedef struct CommonParameters {
    //other members;
    int repeatCount
} commonParams;
```

i have to validate ServerCOnfig values and then assign it to CommonParameters as show below

```
if (serverConfig->opt_repeatCount > 1) {
    commonParams.repeatCount = serverConfig->repeatCount;
}
```

The value of `serverConfig->repeatCount` is some junk(380090700) if not assigned by user. and which is greater than 1 in my case. I need to validate if this `serverConfig->repeatCount` is having a valid value then only pass the if condition
Ultimately my question is to validate a structure variable which is integer for a proper value.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this C++?

Comment: The `malloc` function does not initialize the memory it allocates, its contents is *indeterminate* and using it uninitialized leads to *undefined behavior*. You need to explicitly initialize the structure variables or face the consequences of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it's written in a very C-based style (i.e.  allocating a chunk of memory with `malloc` and then initializing the struct's fields manually). If you adopt a more common C++-based style where you use `new` to allocate your memory and constructors to initialize your fields you'll find these kinds of problems become easier. For example, in your case you could write CommonParameters as:

```
struct CommonParameters {
    CommonParameters(int rc) :
    repeatCount(rc)
    {}

    //other members;
    int repeatCount
};
```

This way CommonParameters is initialized when it's created and you don't have to worry about its initialization status.

NOTE: Because your question is written in what looks like pure C you may have just mis-tagged the question as C++. If so, please change the tag and I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply..! My code is in C++..  Basically i need to validate the value of an integer member(repeatCount) from server config structure and assign it to commonParameter(repeatCount).

Comment: Currently value of repeat count point to a junk value/address if not assigned a value. and which is also greater than 1, and so a positive one(such a 3800700). my if says, if(repeatCount>1) do something and its getting executed even its not assigned. my commonparams has a constructor too with some default values

Comment: 'typedef struct CommonParameters {
    //other members;
    int repeatCount;
 commonParams()
 {
 repeatCount=1;
 }
  } commonParams; '

Comment: There's a bunch of different options for validating that repeatCount has been initialized. For example, you could do what I suggest and make it so that you can't create a CommonParameters object without setting the repeatCount field. We can discuss other approaches to solving the problem but you would need to explain a bit more about your situation (e.g. why is it that you have to write it in pure C and not take advantage of C++ features like constructors).

Comment: ok let me explain,
there are two structures. ServerCOnfig and CommonParameters. CommonParameter structure has a constructor which sets some default values(say repeatcount=1). as show below
'typedef struct CommonParameters {
    int repeatCount;
 commonParams()
 {
 repeatCount=1;
 }
  } commonParams; '

Comment: I expose Server config to Users and get data and internally assign those values to commonparameters struct members and use it, And now, if User did not set value of repeatCount?, it ll be pointing to a junk value.(which is greate than 1 and a positive number alwys) my if condition says, if (ServerCOnfig->RepeatCount >0)
  Assign it to Commonparams->repeatCount.

Comment: Now this if is wrong because even if the user dint set the value, my commonParams->repeatCount gets a junk value into it.

Comment: Now my question, How do i validate the repeatCOunt has value or a junk value(a address as 67805899) and only assign which use sets a value. Please share your approach and i will use the same.
  And you can tell me C++ approch as i do need C++.
  Thanks for your patience..! Please Leave a reply asap

Comment: If you initialize repeatCount to 1 when you create CommonParameters then it's not a junk value. Either there's something that you're missing in your explanation or you are not initializing CommonParameters properly. For example, the constructor isn't called if you just cast a block of memory you get from malloc, you have to use new to get a new object or declare it on the stack.